# register new user with spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a question about adding new user using spring and hibernate. I am  using  spring security for authentication and I managed to configure it using oracle db. The next thing I would like to implement is registering new user. What is the usual approach in this case? I read some materials but most of them were designed and implemented with jsp and my client side is written in angularjs. 
What I have so far is a controller with two endpoints `/user` and `/register`

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private RegisterService registerService;

@RequestMapping("/user")
@ResponseBody
public Principal user(Principal user) {
    return user;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void registerUser() {
    User user = new User();
    registerService.save(user);
}
}
```

I believe I need also some service. In my case this is `RegisterService` and implementation of that service RegisterServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class RegisterServiceImpl implements RegisterService {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


@Transactional
@Override
public void save(User user) {
    // what should be the implementation of this method?

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(user);
}
}
```

Here is my `UserDao` entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "username")
private String userName;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "is_enabled")
private boolean isEnabled;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
private Department department;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

public User() {

}

public User(String username, String password, Boolean isEnabled,             Set<UserRole> userRole) { 
    this.userName = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    this.userRole = userRole;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUsername(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return isEnabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
    this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
}

public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}

public Set<UserRole> getUserRole() {
    return this.userRole;
}

public void setUserRole(Set<UserRole> userRole) {
    this.userRole = userRole;
}
```

}

My security config looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
LogoutSuccess logoutSuccess;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .httpBasic()
  .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/profile", "/logout", "/home").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
   .and()
   .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .csrf().disable();
}


@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/app/**");
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
      HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
      repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
      return repository;
    }

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}
```

}

On user registration I would like to set all of the class members in `User` but I am not sure how to achieve that. I dont think creating `@PathVariable` for every class member would be appropriate because I will send sensitive data username and password. Many thanks for your answers!

Comment: Please tell me you are not storing the passwords as plain text in the database.

Comment: You have not clearly mentioned how are you authenticating existing users with spring security. How are you designing ur page with just angularjs. and how are u communicating between client and server. Info u have provided is a bit inadequate

Comment: they are not stored as play text. I am using BCryptPasswordEncoder

Comment: so can u please clarify ur implementation of spring security

Comment: @Acewin added the spring security config.

Comment: No, don't create a path variable, use a form post.  You seem to be not super versed in HTTP, so maybe a learning opportunity there, but POST (and PUT) requests have bodies that can be things like JSON, x-www-urlencoded key value pairs, xml, etc...  Design a payload to convey the message and populate your object from that.  Look into Jackson for spring and json

Answer (score 0):

Your security configuration is too simple. You can add a hell of a lot more to it. For instance, you can add roles, default access page, error page etc. I can see that for registering users you've used post which is good because you need to submit data. However, remember post is non-idempotent meaning that it is not safe to repeat so in your register method in the controller you need to at least use redirect:/your_desired_page after registering if you are not planning to use spring security for this(see the diff between GET and POST for more info). Because you use angular and need to return json I would advise you to use a custom authentication provider instead of UserDetailsService (see [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider)) which will give you more freedom on the return data and error handling.